# Returning a knockout view model on pushstate / popstate

Tags: javascript, html, dom, knockout.js

I've been trying for some time to save a ko viewmodel to the browser history and return it on a popstate event.  Currently no errors are being thrown, but nothing is being changed on the popstate.  The basic flow of what I'm trying goes like this:

```
var storeViewModel = function (){
return ko.toJSON(viewModel);
};

function viewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.records = ko.observableArray();

    // add an object to the array and save view model
    self.addRecord = function () {
         self.records.push(new record());

         //  call the storeViewModel function push viewModel to history
         history.pushState(storeViewModel(), "");
    }

    //  set view model to stored view model object on forward / back  navigation navigation
    window.onpopstate = function (event) {
        self = ko.utils.parseJson(event.state);
     }
}

 ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

I've read the mozilla documentation for this several times.  Everything seems to make sense, but I am having trouble in implementation.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't save the viewmodel, but the *data* it contains.

The most convenient way to do that is by employing automatic mapping. Knockout has the [mapping plugin][1] for this; it allows you to easily turn raw data into a working viewmodel, and a working viewmodel back into raw data.

By default the mapping plugin maps all properties of the raw data to `observable` or `observableArray`, respectively, but that can be fine-tuned in the mapping definition (see documentation).

This basically works like this:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {/* mapping definition */}, self);
```

and back like this:

```
ko.mapping.toJS(self);
```

I'd recommend setting up all your viewmodels so they can bootstrap themselves from raw data:

```
function Record(data) {
    var self = this;
    // init
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, Record.mapping, self);
}
Record.mapping = {
    // mapping definition for Record objects, kept separately as a constructor
    // property to keep it out of the individual Record objects
};
```

and

```
function RecordPlayer(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.records = ko.observableArray();

    self.init(data);

    self.state = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return ko.mapping.toJS(self);
    });
}
RecordPlayer.mapping = {
    // mapping rules for ViewModel objects
    records: {
        create: function (options) {
            return new Record(options.data);
        }
    }
};
RecordPlayer.prototype.init = function (data) {
    // extend a default data layout with the actual data
    data = ko.utils.extend({
        records: []
    }, data);
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, ViewModel.mapping, this);
};
RecordPlayer.prototype.addRecord = function () {
    this.records.push(new Record());
};
```

The mapping plugin keeps track of all the properties it mapped in the `.fromJS` step and only returns those in the `.toJS()` step. Any other properties, like computeds, will be ignored.

That's also the reason for the `ko.utils.extend` - to establish the baseline set of properties that you want the mapping plugin to handle.

The `state` computed now changes every time the state-relevant data changes, due to knockout's built-in dependency tracking.

Now what's left is handling the page load event:

```
// initialize the viewmodel
var player = new RecordPlayer(/* data e.g. from Ajax */);

// subscribe to VM state changes (except for changes due to popState)
var popStateActive = false;
player.state.subscribe(function (data) {
    if (popStateActive) return;
    history.pushState(ko.toJSON(data), "");
});

// subscribe to window state changes
player.utils.registerEventHandler(window, "popstate", function (event) {
    popStateActive = true;
    player.init( ko.utils.parseJson(event.state) );
    popStateActive = false;
});

// and run it
ko.applyBindings(player);
```

---

#### You can expand and run the code snippet below to see it in action.

```js
function Record(data) {
    var self = this;
    // init
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, Record.mapping, self);
}
Record.mapping = {
    // mapping definition for Record objects, kept separately as a constructor
    // property to keep it out of the individual Record objects
};

function RecordPlayer(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.records = ko.observableArray();

    self.init(data);

    self.state = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        return ko.mapping.toJS(self);
    });
}
RecordPlayer.mapping = {
    // mapping rules for RecordPlayer objects
    records: {
        create: function(options) {
            return new Record(options.data);
        }
    }
};
RecordPlayer.prototype.init = function(data) {
    // extend a default data layout with the actual data
    data = ko.utils.extend({
        records: []
    }, data);
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, RecordPlayer.mapping, this);
};
RecordPlayer.prototype.addRecord = function() {
    this.records.push(new Record());
};
RecordPlayer.prototype.pushState = function() {
    history.pushState(this.state(), "");
};


// initialize the viewmodel
var player = new RecordPlayer( /* optional: data e.g. from Ajax */ );
var popStateActive = false;

// subscribe to VM state changes (except for changes due to popState)
player.state.subscribe(function(data) {
    if (popStateActive) return;
    history.pushState(ko.toJSON(data), "");
});

// subscribe to window state changes
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(window, "popstate", function(event) {
    popStateActive = true;
    player.init(ko.utils.parseJson(event.state));
    popStateActive = false;
});

// and run it
ko.applyBindings(player);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<p>Records:
  <span data-bind="foreach: records">
    <span>(o)</span>
  </span>
</p>

<p>There are <span data-bind="text: records().length"></span> records in the player.</p>
<button data-bind="click: addRecord">Add record</button>
<button data-bind="click: function () { history.back(); }">Undo (<code>history.back()<code>)</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough and comprehensive response and suggestions, Tomalak.  You provided a great example, and I think this will do it.  I'm not too familiar with automatic mapping, so I will get familiar with it.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Ben Glad I could help! Repay it by answering a few questions on the site yourself; answering is a great way to learn.

Comment: @Ben Oh, the other mapping plugin is this one: http://coderenaissance.github.io/knockout.viewmodel/ Check it out, maybe you like it better.

Comment: One more thing - I moved the `self.state` computed after the `self.init()` call. ([compare](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31629897/revisions#6fcccedf-156b-4a28-812d-ff79d9d5cb94)) (It's better to do the mapping first and create all computeds after that, this avoids them firing needlessly during the mapping step.)

Comment: Tomalak, thank you for for the updates.  I'm checking out the coderenaissance link right now.  I'll be sure to have a go answering questions where I can.  Thanks!